# How can I Remove Year Month and .html extension from Blogspot URL?

Tags: blogger, permalinks

In Short My Concern is that I want to Custom URL in Blogspot Blogger. As following....

https://ruturajtours.blogspot.com/2022/04/top-10-tallest-lord-shiva-statues-to.html
to
https://ruturajtours.blogspot.com/top-10-tallest-lord-shiva-statues-to

Answer (score 0):

try use this

> https://github.com/jokenox/bloggerjs

Put the code in your head tag

```js
// Configuration
var config = {
  postsDatePrefix: false,
  accessOnly: false,

  useApiV3: false,
  apiKey: "YOUR-API-KEY-HERE"
}
var postsOrPages=["pages","posts"],blogId="<data:blog.blogId/>",urlTotal,fetchIndex=1,ampChar="&amp;"[0],secondRequest=!0,feedPriority=0,nextPageToken;function urlVal(){var url=window.location.pathname;var length=url.length;var urlEnd=url.substring(length-5);if(urlEnd===".html")return 0;else if(length>1)return 1;else return 2}
function urlMod(){var url=window.location.pathname;if(url.substring(1,2)==="p"){url=url.substring(url.indexOf("/",1)+1);url=url.substr(0,url.indexOf(".html"));history.replaceState(null,null,"../"+url)}else{if(!config.postsDatePrefix)url=url.substring(url.indexOf("/",7)+1);else url=url.substring(1);url=url.substr(0,url.indexOf(".html"));history.replaceState(null,null,"../../"+url)}}
function urlSearch(url,database){var pathname=url+".html";database.forEach(function(element){var search=element.search(pathname);if(search!==-1)window.location=element})}
function urlManager(){var validation=urlVal();if(validation===0){if(!config.accessOnly)urlMod()}else if(validation===1){fetchData(postsOrPages[feedPriority],1)}else if(validation===2){if(!config.accessOnly)history.replaceState(null,null,"/")}}
function fetchData(postsOrPages,index){var script=document.createElement("script");if(config.useApiV3){var jsonUrl="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/"+blogId+"/"+postsOrPages+"?key="+config.apiKey+"#maxResults=500#fields=nextPageToken%2Citems(url)#callback=parseData";if(nextPageToken)jsonUrl+="#pageToken="+nextPageToken;nextPageToken=undefined}else{var jsonUrl=window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+"/feeds/"+postsOrPages+"/summary?start-index="+index+"#max-results=150#orderby=published#alt=json-in-script#callback=parseData"}
jsonUrl=jsonUrl.replace(/#/g,ampChar);script.type="text/javascript";script.src=jsonUrl;document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script)}
function parseData(json){var database=[];if(!config.useApiV3){if(!urlTotal){urlTotal=parseInt(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t)}
try{json.feed.entry.forEach(function(element,index){var entry=json.feed.entry[index];entry.link.forEach(function(element,index){if(entry.link[index].rel==="alternate")database.push(entry.link[index].href)})})}catch(e){}}else{try{json.items.forEach(function(element,index){database.push(element.url)})}catch(e){}
nextPageToken=json.nextPageToken}
urlSearch(window.location.pathname,database);if(urlTotal>150){fetchIndex+=150;urlTotal-=150;fetchData(postsOrPages[feedPriority],fetchIndex)}else if(nextPageToken){fetchData(postsOrPages[feedPriority])}else if(secondRequest){nextPageToken=undefined;urlTotal=0;fetchIndex=1;secondRequest=!1;if(feedPriority===0){feedPriority=1;fetchData("posts",1)}else if(feedPriority===1){feedPriority=0;fetchData("pages",1)}}}
function bloggerJS(priority){if(priority)feedPriority=priority;urlManager()}
bloggerJS()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Blogger does not support the above Permalink feature. Although, there's a workaround.
You can leverage the custom redirect feature.

Go to **Blogger Settings > Errors and redirects > Custom redirects**

[image]

From there you can add a **FROM URL** to **TO URL**

So you'll be sharing your link like this:

https://ruturajtours.blogspot.com/top-10-tallest-lord-shiva-statues-to

Which will redirect it to the original post

https://ruturajtours.blogspot.com/2022/04/top-10-tallest-lord-shiva-statues-to.html

Answer (score 0):

it has to run server side, i managed to change the permalink. demo:

> [www.buzz.my.id](http://www.buzz.my.id)